# Are there several performance penalties for using Objects with functions and mixins, rather than prototypes?

Tags: javascript, performance, oop

One common way to do OOP in JavaScript involves using objects with functions attached to them, instead of using the built-in prototypes, constructors and the `new` operator. Mixins are often used to combine 2 objects by pasting member-variables, simulating inheritance.

Measuring whether that kind of practice has consequences for performance is hard, because specific benchmarks don't tell much in this case. Are there such performance penalties, and how severe are them?

Comment: How severe they are only a custom benchmark for a specific case can tell.

Comment: OO performance only matters if you instantiate tons of objects. Also, for many apps, network latency is a much bigger factor.

Comment: I think it might even improve performance (shorter lookup) but increase memory consumption (more properties). Depends on the application design which of the two is better.

Comment: @downvoter/closer, mind explaining?

Answer (score 2):

If you do OOP using constructors, prototypes, `new`s, etc, this is something V8 (JS engine in Chrome and Node.js) specially optimizes for. Your user properties will be even stored side by side with their internal properties, like in C++ or Java objects.

One of the benchmarks used to tune V8 is heavily object oriented like this http://octane-benchmark.googlecode.com/svn/latest/deltablue.js

If you attach properties dynamically or do some other sleazy tricks, you will of course confuse the heuristics for this and probably set yourself back.

This is of course engine specific.

I should also mention the general disclaimer that if you are doing UI code like "click handler shows an text area", then this doesn't matter. You could be collecting stack traces on every method call and not notice any perf issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about this you could mix in on the prototype but as Bergi says; when calling a method many times it actually has a shorter look up if you have the method on the instance instead of on it's prototype.

Here is how to mixin on the prototype:

```
function mixin(source, target){
  for(thing in source){
    if(source.hasOwnProperty(thing)){
      target[thing]=source[thing];
    }
  }
};
var canSpeak = function(){
  //initialize instance specific values
  this.canSpeakMessage="Hello World";
  this.someArrayThatNeedsToBeInitialized=[];
};
canSpeak.prototype.speak = function(){
  console.log(this.canSpeakMessage);
}
var Test= function(){
  //init instance specific values for canSpeak
  canSpeak.apply(this,arguments);
};
mixin(canSpeak.prototype,Test.prototype);


var t = new Test();
t.speak();//=Hello World
```

Comment: The beginning statement is false for V8 (and probably any other good engine too), a method will not be looked up on prototype (well of course it is looked up when the cache is cold). This is the strength of prototypes, you can validate that all the cached methods and property look ups are not stale with a single hidden class pointer check on the object. And they will be valid as long as you don't do sleazy tricks like this. If you want to use mixins, mixin them statically to the prototype when defining the "class" (prototype and constructor).

Comment: @Esailija `beginning statement is false` It used to be the case though as I remember. Just like passing a closure is faster than using Function.prototype.bind. This will probably be corrected later as bind will be used more and more instead of closures. `as long as you don't do sleazy tricks like this` and `If you want to use mixins, mixin them statically to the prototype when defining the "class"` If you read the code you'd notice that the functions are being mixed in on the prototype when the "class" is defined so could you explain what exactly you mean by that?

Comment: .bind has different functionality from closure, it's an apples and oranges comparison. Inline caches have been core feature of V8 from the beginning, I doubt it was never the case but don't have time to check. Even though your code does one thing, you say another.

Comment: @Esailija  Maybe there is a misunderstanding apples(bind): `setTimeout(myfunction.bind(aninstance,arg1,arg2),100)` oranges(closure): `setTimeout(function(){aninstance.myfunction(arg1,arg2);},100)` Can't find a reference right now to instance functions being faster to look up than prototype (do remember something of `[].splice.call` being faster than `Array.prototype.slice.call` http://jsperf.com/array-prototype-splice-retrieval I usually advice people to add functions to prototype and only use module pattern on the prototype (private functions saving this to be used in invoking object context)

Comment: @Esailija bind versus closure (called self in the test) http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-closure-setup/6 This doesn't prevent me from using bind though, it's a good way to prevent memory leaks because you can add unexpected stuff in closures that won't get garbaged.

Comment: Your jsperf is re-defining static functions, just see http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-emulate/13. You will not get any memory leaks unless you write some really nasty code that is almost impossible to write by accident. My point about bind was its convoluted semantics such as what happens when you call the returned function as constructor? retrieve .length? retrieve .prototype? a closure doesn't need to worry about any of that. `Array.prototype.slice.call` is completely irrelevant to what I meant. I meant that calling `this.fn()` is fast if `fn` is on [[prototype]] of this