# Inherit from 2 objects

Tags: javascript

I have a question about object inheritance with Object.create.

I have two objects, that should behave like interfaces. `Object3D` and `Light`. `Object3D` presents real object in 3D space. It has its position in space and it should have some functions to for example change this position. `Light` is everything that glows. And every light has its color.

```
// I have resons to use iif, dont bother with that ;) 

var Object3D = (function() {

    var Object3D = function() {
        this.position = vec3.create();
    };

    return Object3D;
})();


var Light = (function() {

    var Light = function() {
        this.color = new Array(4);
    };

    return Light;
})();
```

Now, I want to have two another objects, which will be 'classes'. First one is `AmbientLight`. `AmbientLight` doesnt have position, because it just glows everywhere. So it inherits from `Light`. The other one is `PointLight`. `PointLight` is `Light`, but it has also position, because it doesn't glow everywhere. It has some range. So it should inherit also from `Object3D`. How can I do it? Can I merge results from Object.create?

```
var AmbientLight = (function() {

    var AmbientLight = function() {
        Light.call(this);
    };

    AmbientLight.prototype = Object.create(Light.prototype);

    return AmbientLight;
})();


var PointLight = (function() {

    var PointLight = function() {
        Light.call(this);
        Object3D.call(this);
        this.range = 10.0;
    };

    // this isnt correct
    // how to make it correct? 
    PointLight.prototype = Object.create(Light.prototype);
    PointLight.prototype = Object.create(Object3D.prototype); 

    return PointLight;
})();
```

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can do multiple inheritance.

Comment: Well does my example make sence? Im sure I can do it another way, but Im happy with this one...

Comment: It makes sense, but I don't know much about inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple inheritance/prototypes in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9163341/multiple-inheritance-prototypes-in-javascript)

Comment: [Favor composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Comment: you can use mixins with constructor functions http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899537/1641941

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got exactly the right idea.  Simply merge your two objects together where you're setting the prototype:

```
PointLight.prototype = Object.create(Light.prototype);
var obj3D = Object.create(Object3D.prototype);

for (var key in obj3D) {
    if (obj3D.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        PointLight.prototype.key = obj3D.key;
    }
}
```

Of course, you have all your normal ugly issues that you get when dealing with multiple inheritance - namely, if you have any member with a common name in both objects, the `Object3D` member will overwrite the `Light` member.