# Why is my javascript mixin not working?

Tags: javascript, mixins

Take a look at this `klass` implementation (from Javascript Web Applications by Alex MacCaw.) that adds prototype methods for instantiated objects:

```
var Class = function(){
  var klass = function(){
    this.init.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  klass.prototype.init  = function(){};

  // Shortcut to access prototype
  klass.fn = klass.prototype;

  // Shortcut to access class
  klass.fn.parent = klass;

  // Adding class properties
  klass.extend = function(obj){
    var extended = obj.extended;
    for(var i in obj){
      klass[i] = obj[i];
    }
    if (extended) extended(klass)
  };

  // Adding instance properties
  klass.include = function(obj){
    var included = obj.included;
    for(var i in obj){
      klass.fn[i] = obj[i];
    }
    if (included) included(klass)
  };

  return klass;
};
```

The `adding instance properties` bit does not work for me.

```
var Restaurant = new Class;

Restaurant.prototype = {
  init: function(name, cuisine, location) {
    this.name = name || 'needs a name';
    this.cuisine = cuisine || 'needs a cuisine';
    this.location = location || 'needs a location';
  }
}

Restaurant.include({
  save: function(id) {  
    return 'saved';
  },
  destroy: function(id) { /* ... */ },
  included: function(klass) {
    console.log(klass, " was included!");
  }
});

var chow = new Restaurant('Chows', 'chinese', 'mumbai');
```

The problem is the `chow` object does not respond to the save method. The included callback however works.

I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'save'`

Why is that? How do I fix it?

Comment: Maybe this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18899537/1641941 because you never know how many mixins you may use the instance variables for the mixin are initialized in functions starting with `initMixin` and called on creating the object (in the constructor body).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute this line:

```
Restaurant.prototype = {...};
```

You just replaced the entire prototype of the Restaurant object so it no longer has the methods that were supposed to be put there from `klass`.  It won't have `.include()` for example and with no `.include()`, that method can't add your `.save()` so therefore there's no `.save()`.

The way this `klass` code works that I assume you got from the book, you don't assign to `.prototype` (because that wrecks stuff that is supposed to be there).  You either call `.include()` to add new methods to the prototype or `.extend()` to add new methods to an instance.

Comment: So now tell me: where do I put my init code? Inside the include code block?

Comment: @AmitErandole - yes, if you're trying to add something to the prototype (so it's on all objects of that type), you use `.include()` to add it.  It sounds like you need to make sure you understand what the `.include()` and `.extend()` methods are doing and what they are used for because the point of using this framework is so they are there to be used.